# NPE when removing a Dynamic Spring Integration Flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Hi in our application we are creating certain dynamic integrations flows that we remove and create on the flow . 
Mostly things have worked great but we have observed the below error sometimes specially due to the integration flow trying to remove dependent beans . Can someone comment whether this is a bug or we are missing anything . Error Trace below

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: null 

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resetBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912) 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.removeBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891) 
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowContext.removeDependantBeans(IntegrationFlowContext.java:203) 
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowContext.remove(IntegrationFlowContext.java:189) at
```

code that removes integration flow

```
 flowContext.remove("flowId");
```

Update of the invoking code

```
 if (discoveryService.isFLowPresent(flowId))
  {
     LOG.debug("Removing and creating flow [{}]", flowId);
     discoveryService.removeIntegrationFlow(fc.getFeedId());
     LOG.debug("Removing Old Job and create fresh one with new params [{}]", flowId); 
     try
     {
        discoveryService.createFlow(fc.getFeedId());
     }
     catch (ExecutionException e)
     {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error while starting flow for Integration adapter [{}]" + fc.getFeedId(), e);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please, share some minimal code to reproduce and also a version you are using. Sounds like a race condition, when you create and remove flows concurrently. Also it feels like you use the same dependent bean in different flows... So, please, more info into the studio! Otherwise we are going to waste a lot of time with the question answer.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan let us investigate more on the same , you are right we are doing the same pasted a snipped of the code in the post .

Comment: I think you are in the old Spring Integration version, where there is no concurrency fix yet. So, you need to wrap your code into the `synchrinized`  block to ensure exclusive access to the `IntegrationFlowContext` methods.

Comment: Currently on SI 5.0.7 is there a fix in 5.0.8 or later ? We had a workaround to avoid this issue basically to create a different flow in case of adhoc flows .

Comment: Fix for what? The issue is still not clear from your perspective. Not one said yet that you are using the Framework right way. Let's start from the business requirements! What you would like to achieve? Why one would need to register and de-register `IntegrationFlow` s on the fly for the same `id` ?

Comment: Was suggesting as you said you are in an old SI version . The use case is we have some optional arguments we need to pass when rerunning our integration flows . For this as we don't have the ability to change existing flows we basically remove and create the flows for the same id [feed] and then start the updated flow .The workaround I mentioned was to make these use a different id in case of adhoc submissions . We currently don't bounce our running flows programatically  this is only in case of adhoc flows .

Comment: What is that argument you need to pass? Can't it be resolved at runtime in some singleton, so you will have only one static `IntegrationFlow` instance? The point is that there are many hooks can be used instead of abusing runtime flow registration

Comment: Arguments are mostly a map of params .Yes in most of our adapters it works like that and we only restart in case there is a major configuration change [like in case of ftp/sftp connections] by doing it manually via an Api.This case comes in where we have some of our custom aws glue batch adapters wherein we need to pass run-time params to update the base aws job when we start the adapter/flow again . Easiest way we figured out was via integration flow registrations [though was bit skeptical in doing the create and delete] ,  surely we will try to explore alternative ways .

Comment: The idea of singleton or  spel expressions for such params also looks good .Thanks for the help

Comment: Please, take a look into this as a possible alternative: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-rotating-server-advice. Also think about minimizing your dynamic `IntegrationFlow` as much as possible. I'm pretty sure you can just send some output of the channel adapter  to the existing `MessageChannel` singleton bean. However the `synchronized` over your `delete/register` code should be fine, too.

Comment: Also, pay attention here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/d0603a80ff5d89d14681ed6acec17c94c08e9564

Comment: Ya will need to check that, most of our flows originate from [custom and oob] inbound adapters created and configured based on dynamic configurations .We do need to have dynamic flows as these in our app allow the user to create flows dynamically [there is only one unique id generated for each flow we configure].

Comment: These flows work fine in the usual vanilla flow, only alternate case being the adhoc rerun scenarios wherein user can change the configs of the inbound adapter . I will check the above to see if we can minimize bouncing them specially in the adhoc rerun case also was thinking if there could be an alternative to pass those params when stopping and starting an existing flow and another way is we will have a unique id for the adhoc rerun flow so we can avoid these race conditions and conflicts with the pre-existing flows.. .